# MySql, PHP display Picture on HTml

Tags: php, mysql, html

im trying to display the picture saved in the database using Php, but what i get is Url link which was saved in the database and not the picture, i think the syntax is wrong.

```php
<?php
echo "<table border=\"1\" align=\"center\">"; 
echo "<tr> 
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Description</th> 
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Manufacturer</th>
    <th>Image</th> 
  </tr>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Description'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Price'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Manufacturer'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['ImageURL'] ."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; 
?>
</p>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct an `<img>` element, not just output the image URL.

Try replacing this: `$row['ImageURL']`

With this: `"<img src='".$row['ImageURL']."' />`

Comment: this works like magic, so how do i change the image size i.e width and height

Comment: @Elnino: You need to find yourself a decent introductory book on HTML.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

`echo "<td>" .$row['ImageURL'] ."</td>";`

it looks like you'll want that to be:

`echo "<td><img src='" .$row['ImageURL'] ."' /></td>";`

Comment: this works too, so how do i change the image size i.e width and height

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo "<td>" .$row['ImageURL'] ."</td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td><img src='" .$row['ImageURL'] ."' style='width: 200px; height: 350px;' /></td>";
```

Modify the values 200px and 350px to whatever you want, just keep the 'px' suffix.