# How to show a picture in a php table from a sql

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySql, PHP display Picture on HTml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441183/mysql-php-display-picture-on-html)

How can I show the picture ' in the screenshot part of my ocde' in my php table ? When i show the table on my website I don't want to see the name off the picture like my code is doing now but I want to see the real picture:

This code will get all the information from a sql database .

My code

```
echo "<table class=showtable>";
echo "<tr>
<td class=show >".$row['ID']."</td>
<td class=show2>".$row['DateTime']."</td>
<td class=show3>".$row['Stock']."</td>
<td class=show4>".$row['Type']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Trade']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Entry']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Stoploss']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Target1']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Target2']."</td>
<td class=show6>".$row['Explination']."</td>
<td class=show7>".$row['Screenshot']."</td> </tr>";
 echo "</table>";
  }
```

Comment: you saved your image in the database or reference in the db ?? if it is then its a bad practice.

Comment: '<img src="'.$row['Screenshot'].'" alt="img">';

Answer (score 0):

just add 1 img tag with src your img name..

```
echo "<table class=showtable>";
echo "<tr>
<td class=show >".$row['ID']."</td>
<td class=show2>".$row['DateTime']."</td>
<td class=show3>".$row['Stock']."</td>
<td class=show4>".$row['Type']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Trade']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Entry']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Stoploss']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Target1']."</td>
<td class=show5>".$row['Target2']."</td>
<td class=show6>".$row['Explination']."</td>
<td class=show7><img src='".$row['Screenshot']."' /></td> </tr>";
 echo "</table>";
  }
```

You have to write and the folder if that image is in folder
`<img src='/img/".$row['Screenshot']."' />`

Comment: I added this code and now I see the symbol of a pictures but its not showing the picture . Do I add something to the code the files are stored like .png files

Comment: inside the src="" there must be 100% correct path to your picture..

if you can open it at localhost/img/pictureName.jpg 
then set src='/img/".$row['Screenshot']."' else change it to your correct path..

Answer (score 0):

Yes above answer is correct just use the image tag and past u'r image path in image tag src attribute. Then the image will display using you php path.

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/10480.htm

Comment: I did I use .png files but with this code I got a symbol in my table of a picture I want to see the real picture do I add something like print ?

Comment: The image path is wrong, 
use firebug to debug on the go
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/
this is a firefox add-on u change the image path on the browser

Answer (score 0):

You should use image file extension with concatenation '.jpg' or '.png'